# Program isn't reading from file

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will read input from a file and sort that input into arrays. Currently, when asked to print one of the arrays, I am getting [Ljava.lang.String;@2f7a2457. I am unsure as to where the issue lies.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class friends {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    String[] friendslist = new String[50];
    String[] birthdates = new String [50];
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("friends1.txt"));
     
    int friendsamount = 0;
    String name = "string";
    while((name == "string")) {
        
            friendslist[friendsamount] = name;
            friendsamount++;
        
        name = input.nextLine();
    
    
    
    for(int i=0; i < friendsamount; i++ ) {
        friendslist[i] = input.nextLine();
    
    }
     
     
     
     for(int k = 0; k < friendsamount; k++) {
         System.out.println(friendslist);
     }
}

}
}
```

Comment: Use `System.out.println(friendslist[k]);`; `while((name == "string")) {` isn't how you should be comparing strings - see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more details

Comment: You're trying to print the whole array, rather than each individual element.

Comment: searching this site you should find [Strange output when printing array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38548693/85421) which points to [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409784/85421)

Comment: BTW do you really want to add `"string"` as first name, and continue adding it until a different name is found in the file? Also correct your indentation - it does NOT reflect the code (e.g. the `for` loops are inside the `while` loop)

Answer (score 1):

**Fix 1:**

Wrong: `while((name == "string")) {`

Correct: `while((name.equals("string"))) {`

A String is not a primitive datatype but a complex one. Only values of primitive datatypes are compared with `==`. You must use `equals()` for comparing values of complex datatypes.

**Fix 2:**

Wrong: `System.out.println(friendslist);`

Correct 1: `System.out.println(friendslist[k]);`

Correct 2: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(friendslist));`

Your variable is an array. If you system out the variable, `toString()` is called, which returns the reference hash and not the content. If you want to print the content, you must iterate over the array and print every single element. Or use `Arrays.toString()`.